# Combining multiple ms access queries into one existing table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm stuck with my poor knowledge of MS Access query. I have 2 tables.

```
1. Table Output and
2. Dump : this is a linked table to an excel file
```

I have used Concatenate user function found at http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

I have total 8 different queries as below:

```
Query_1 : DELETE table FROM [Output];

Query_2 : INSERT INTO [Output] (SERVICE_REQUEST_NO) SELECT DISTINCT SERVICE_REQUEST_NO
FROM Dump
ORDER BY SERVICE_REQUEST_NO;

Query_3 : SELECT DISTINCT i.SERVICE_REQUEST_NO, ConcatRelated(
"EMERTEL_NO",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") AS EMERTEL_NOss
FROM Dump AS i;

Query_4 : SELECT DISTINCT i.SERVICE_REQUEST_NO, ConcatRelated(
"LOGGED_DATE",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") AS LOGGED_DATEss
FROM Dump AS i;

Query_5 : SELECT DISTINCT i.SERVICE_REQUEST_NO, ConcatRelated(
"PART_NO",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") AS PART_NOss
FROM Dump AS i;

Query_6 : SELECT DISTINCT i.SERVICE_REQUEST_NO, ConcatRelated(
"PART_DESC",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") AS PART_DESCss
FROM Dump AS i;

Query_7 : SELECT DISTINCT i.SERVICE_REQUEST_NO, ConcatRelated(
"STATUS_DESC",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") AS STATUS_DESCss
FROM Dump AS i;

Query_8 : SELECT DISTINCT i.SERVICE_REQUEST_NO, ConcatRelated(
"STATUS_DATE",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") AS STATUS_DATEss
FROM Dump AS i;
```

My problem is i want to update or insert the out put of all these queries to table "Output" for matching `"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO"` field

Do let me know if you want to have a look on my MS Access database.

Please help me.

Thanks for support [Table Output fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBZ5a.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you should combine this into one query.  The way you have it each query selects just one column from the `Dump` table.  If you keep the queries separate you'd have to `JOIN` each of them, which is a pain and creates more opportunities for error.  As one query it would look like:

```
INSERT INTO [Output] 
(
    SERVICE_REQUEST_NO,
    EMERTEL_NOss,
    LOGGED_DATEss,
    PART_NOss,
    PART_DESCss,
    STATUS_DESCss,
    STATUS_DATEss
) 
SELECT DISTINCT
SERVICE_REQUEST_NO,
Concatrelated(
"EMERTEL_NO",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") 
    AS EMERTEL_NOss,
Concatrelated(
"LOGGED_DATE",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") 
    AS LOGGED_DATEss,
Concatrelated(
"PART_NO",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") 
    AS PART_NOss,
Concatrelated(
"PART_DESC",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") 
    AS PART_DESCss,
Concatrelated(
"STATUS_DESC",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") 
    AS STATUS_DESCss,
Concatrelated(
"STATUS_DATE",
"Dump",
"SERVICE_REQUEST_NO = """ & [SERVICE_REQUEST_NO] & """") 
    AS STATUS_DATEss
FROM [Dump]
```

I'm not exactly sure why you're using `DISTINCT` in each query without seeing your actual data.  For the purposes of this answer I'm assuming that you're using it to avoid exact duplicate rows in `[Output`.  The single `DISTINCT` at the top of my select list takes care of that.